# Java: Interrupted Exception: awaitTermination

Tags: java

I have the following code, and interrupted exception occurs at the arrow below. How should I rectify this ? I believe the ‘shutdown’ and ‘awaittermination’ are implemented correctly. It is the final if statement  that is causing the interrupted exception. I just want to check that the executor is shutdown properly and all tasks are terminated or completed properly on the final if statement.

```
        try {
            cancelTaskAndDisconnectClient();
            System.out.println("2. Disconnected @ " + LocalDateTime.now() + " !!!");

            // Disable new tasks from being submitted
            executor.shutdown();
            // wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
            if(!executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                // Cancel currently executing tasks
                executor.shutdownNow();
                if(!executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {   <-- where exception occurred
                    System.err.println("Executor did not terminate");
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            executor.shutdownNow();
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is the exception i received.

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2109)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1454)
    at samples.testbed.DataProcessing$CancelMktDataTask.run(DataProcessing.java:134) <- this is the line in my file
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**UPDATE:** I have updated the code as follow. And I realised that issue is that even after I call `shutdown`,`awaitTermination`, `shutdownNow`, the `Executor` is shut down but **never terminated**.

```
public void shutdownshutdownAndAwaitTermination() {
    // Disable new tasks from being submitted
    executor.shutdownNow();
    try {
        // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
        if (!executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            executor.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
               // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
               if (!executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                   System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
             }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted               
        executor.shutdownNow();
        // Preserve interrupt status
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

When I run the code above as below:

```
        System.out.println("2. Disconnected @ " + LocalDateTime.now() + " !!!");
        System.err.println("BEFORE: Executor is Shut Down: " + executor.isShutdown() + "; Executor is Terminated: " + executor.isTerminated());
        shutdownshutdownAndAwaitTermination();
        System.err.println("AFTER: Executor is Shut Down: " + executor.isShutdown() + "; Executor is Terminated: " + executor.isTerminated());
```

And the output is:

```
BEFORE: Executor is Shut Down: false; Executor is Terminated: false
AFTER: Executor is Shut Down: true; Executor is Terminated: false
2. Disconnected @ 2020-03-12T16:33:15.884436400 !!!
```

And the "Disconnected" print comes after the "before/after" when the order should really  be reversed. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: "_How should I rectify this?_" – that would depend on what you want to happen and whether or not the thread is already interrupted before calling `#awaitTermination`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It would be helpful to get more information about what you want to do. Now you are catching an exception because you force interupt the worker of your executor. You can just handle this exception however you want in the catch block

Comment: Not really related to your question but it's often better to add 
 a `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` when you catch an `InterruptedException` to restore the state of the thread.

Comment: _How should I rectify this ?_  Do you want to know how to catch the `InterruptedException` what you trying to accomplish here ?

Comment: You're not doing the above shutdown on a thread being terminated by the pool?

Comment: updated question above.